# VBA - Defining a userform to call upon it later

Tags: vba, excel, global-variables, userform

Sorry in advance if this isn't clear but for some reason my code stopped working recently and i have no idea why.

Basically ive created an excel vba program at my work to do reports (i.e. a stove report or a tree report). There is a cover form which requires the user to enter various details for the report (i.e attendee, date, address etc...). Once this is done they then select a report to complete (there are 5 different userforms they can go to from the cover page). For example, if they select Electrical they then can select either a General, Stove or Hot Water System report (keep this in mind). Say instead they chose Plumbing, they can choose a General or Hot water System Report. Heres my problem... i have back or return buttons on all the userforms (except the cover page) and i use the same userform for the Hot water System and General reports for both electrical and plumbing (because the textboxes, check boxes are identical). With all this in mind..... (sorry....).....

How do i define what userform (plumbing or electrical) to return too?

can post code if needed

Comment: Yes, you should post your code so we can give you specific feedback and direction.

Comment: You mean back to the cover page to select a different userform? Depends how you design the Userform, there will be different approach. So please post code and screenshot  of UserForm.

Answer (score 0):

You could add e.g. `Parent` property to the child Form and so the child knows about its parent. HTH.

Simple example with two Forms: `UserForm1` is *parent*, `UserForm2` is *child*.

```
' This is parent Form

Private child As UserForm2

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set child = New UserForm2
    Set child.Parent = Me ' here the parent is set so the child knows it
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
    child.Show
End Sub
```

---

```
' This is Child Form which knows about it's parent

Private m_parent As Object

Public Property Get Parent() As Object
    Set Parent = m_parent
End Property

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal vNewValue As Object)
    Set m_parent = vNewValue
End Property

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Go back to parent
    Me.Hide
    m_parent.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the help I ended using the following solution. I declared returnform as a global object variable and just set it every time I hit the button to change user forms. So when I hit the back button I called could call returnform.show.

Comment: Yes, the global variable could work.You store the previous userform so each user forms knows where to return.But I personally try not to use global variables in general but prefer the object oriented way of solving problems.